# Delete line of cell text in my text file in swift

Tags: ios, swift

i want to delete the line of text in the list file given under the if editMode == delete function which ever one was swiped on to delete i want it to delete that line of text in the file.

i read the file and parse it into the table view then when the user swipes to delete i want to delete the certain line of text in the file that cell.labelText?.text is if that makes sense. I cant seem to find anywhere that explains my particualr case. so please help me!!!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ManageVC: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    //parse sources text file
    var sourcesList = [String:String]()
    var sourcesArray = NSMutableArray()
    var editMode = false

    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
    var idgen = ""
    func generateRandomDigits(_ digitNumber: Int) -> String {
        var number = ""
        for i in 0..<digitNumber {
            var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
            while randomNumber == 0 && i == 0 {
                randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(10)
            }
            number += "\(randomNumber)"
        }
        return number
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sourcesArray.count
    }
    func tableSetup(){
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

            let source = sourcesArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text = "\((source as AnyObject).value(forKey: "sourcename")!)"
            //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\((source as AnyObject).value(forKey: "sourceurl")!)"

            return cell

        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        let source = sourcesArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\((source as AnyObject).value(forKey: "sourcename")!)"
        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\((source as AnyObject).value(forKey: "sourceurl")!)"

        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editMode == true {
            if editingStyle == .delete{
                sourcesArray.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        }
    }



    var sourceUrlText: UITextField?
    var ref: DatabaseReference!


    @IBOutlet weak var addBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var editBtn: UIBarButtonItem!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.table.reloadData()
        }

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ManageVC.sourceRefresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        table.addSubview(refresher)

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.dataSource = self

        let dir:NSURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last! as NSURL
        let fileurl =  dir.appendingPathComponent("sources.list")

        let mgr = FileManager.default
        if mgr.fileExists(atPath: fileurl!.path) {

            do {

                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: fileurl!.path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

                let reading = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]

                for i in 0..<reading.count {

                    let data : [String] = reading[i].components(separatedBy: ", ")

                    sourcesList["sourcename"] = "\(data[0])"
                    //sourcesList["sourceurl"] = "\(data[1])"

                    sourcesArray.add(sourcesList)

                }

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }

        }


    }

    @IBAction func addBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let addSource = UIAlertController(title: "Add Source:", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        addSource.addTextField(configurationHandler: sourceUrlText)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default, handler: self.okHandler)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        addSource.addAction(cancelAction)
        addSource.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(addSource, animated: true)
    }
    func okHandler(alert: UIAlertAction!){
        if idgen == "" {
            source()
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "refreshingShow", sender: self)
        }


    }
    func sourceUrlText(textField: UITextField!){

        sourceUrlText = textField
        sourceUrlText?.text = "http://"

    }
    @IBAction func editBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        addBtn.isEnabled = true
        editBtn.isEnabled = false
        editMode = true
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        addBtn.isEnabled = false
        editBtn.isEnabled = true
        editMode = false
    }
    func source(){
        let dir:NSURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).last! as NSURL
        let fileurl =  dir.appendingPathComponent("sources.list")

        let string = ((self.sourceUrlText?.text)!) + "\n"
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileurl!.path) {
            var err:NSError?
            if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileurl!.path) {
                fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
                fileHandle.write(data)
                fileHandle.closeFile()
                do {
                    self.table.reloadData()
                    refresher.endRefreshing()
                    let readSources = try String(contentsOfFile: fileurl!.path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    print(readSources)
                } catch {

                }
            }
            else {
                print("Can't open fileHandle \(err)")
            }
        }
        else {
        }
    }
    @objc func sourceRefresh() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableSetup()
            self.table.reloadData()
        }
        refresher.endRefreshing()
    }

}
```

Comment: You don’t need to. You may save a temporary file in memory from sourcearray after each delete. At certain time, save the temporary file as the original one. Then you got the updated file. The key is how you construct a file from the sourceArray.

Comment: @E.Coms well how do i get that line of the file that already exists?

Comment: let reading = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n") as [String]\n

                for i in 0..<reading.count { \n , So you parse here.

Comment: @E.Coms yes thats where the original file comes from. i tried your idea of saving a file but its coming out with { and sourcename= "" in my table view

Comment: @E.coms im not sure how to get rid of that so its just the remainder of strinsg that are in the table view

Comment: @E.Coms can you provided a in depth answer of what you are trying to explain?

Comment: I notice you don’t need function setuptable() enclosure. Your table view data source may not be called. You may need to reload your table view after deleting sometime to guarantee its updated.  You can consider put beginupdate and endupdate around the delete table view cell code.

Comment: @E.Coms So if it’s deleted from the array...how to I wrote the strings in the array back into a text file as strings only?

Comment: sourceArray.joined(separator: "\n")

Comment: @E.Coms abs that’ll write it back to the file??

Comment: Yes.  I think should be

Comment: @E.Coms how can i be sure? the .   sources array isnt written to file already its populated from the file and i need to wrote back to it wiht updated data

Comment: Then write to a temp tile. You can overwrite the original file after validation.  It's a serious operation and should not miss.

Comment: @E.Coms how would you recommend writeing .to a temp file? sorry ofr all the questions

Comment: You cannot overwrite your original file without verification. If the source is too big, It's better to save it to a temp file for future use.

Comment: @E.Coms i think the problem is that the table view is beong read off of the sources.list file and the user needs to be able to add and delete entrys from it.

Comment: It is right. You don't delete the array. but if they need the updated source, you just present the temp one

Comment: okay i see so what is the best way of doing this temp file situation? explain using code if your coukd?